# Is it possible to set the attributes of source and target nodes in 'from_pandas_dataframe()'

Tags: pandas, attributes, networkx

I have built a graph using the dataframe 'my_df':

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0  'a'    'b'    1000
1  'c'    'd'    2000
2  'e'    'f'    3000
3  'g'    'h'    4000
```

source node: col_1 and target node: col_2. I want to use the components of col_3 as attributes only for the source nodes. Is it possible to set this just using 'from_pandas_dataframe'? Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to set the node attributes in a network graph for just the nodes in 'col_1'? If so what are these attributes?

Comment: Yes.I have built a graph using the above pandas dataframe. I was wondering if I could set the attributes on source node directly from the "from_pandas_dataframe".

Comment: No, you'd need to iterate over your nodes and then lookup the attribute from col_3 and assign unfortunately, it'd be better if you have the information up front to construct the graph using the df initially

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help!